# Regular Expression match repeated alphanumeric characters if \1 is not supported

Tags: regex, re2

in [RE2 syntax](https://re2.googlecode.com/hg/doc/syntax.html), backreference such as \1 is not supported. Then how to match a string with repeated characters? For example, I want to match a string that should meet such criteria:
1. contain exactly 17 alphanumeric chars, excluding i,o,q and I,O,Q
2. also exclude those strings that contain a same char that repeats for 17 times.

I get `r'\b[^iIoOqQ\W]{17}\b'` for my first critiria, how about the 2nd one?

Comment: I honestly wouldn't use a regular expression for NOT(same character repeats X times). If you can just write a function to test the string for that, do.

Comment: @rikkigibson my problem was originally raised in a background where I want to apply the filter in a Google Bigquery  query statement (SQL liked). so functions was not a choice at that time. But Bigquery provide JavaScript UDF recently which makes function feasible.  Thank you any way for your suggestion